# Android - How to display 4 text views with Icons?

Tags: android, image, position

I want to display 4 texts with images exactly like showed in this screenshot:

[image]

Notice the 4 texts at the buttom of the image, with the icons next to them.

My question is how do I do it, I mean, how do I attach an icon to each text field and display it symmetrically at the bottom of the page.

I want to position my texts with the icons exactly like this example.

Thanks for your help, it's a really great exercise for a newbie :)

Dvir

Comment: you just posted a similar question few minutes ago, last time you asked for textviews and now you want images too. Why don't you try experimenting first. The user had answered your question. It has enough for you to move on and start doing on your own. You cant just ask direct solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `drawableLeft` for this

```
<TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="24dip"
        android:maxLines="1"
       />
```

**OR**

In java code

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTV);
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon_1, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a `TextView`, and add for example `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/your_icon"`
Use left/right depending of where you want your icon.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout

     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Text"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Text"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Text"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Text"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideal approach to implement this would be:

```
textView.setCompoundDrawables(getDrawable(R.drawable.image), 15), null, null, null);
```

add below function to your code as well:

```
public Drawable getDrawable(int drawable, float form_factor) {
    Drawable top = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(drawable);
    top.setBounds(0, 0, (int)form_factor, (int)form_factor);
    return top;
}
```

This way your can set/choose/resize your text-icons appropriately(by adjusting the value of form-factor) *which is not possible when done through xml*.

NOTE: I've written above function for square-drawables, for rectangular images we will have to do `setBounds` accordingly.