# Action Bar - items with text at bottom of the icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar

What I want to achieve is following type of action bar:

[image: description]

Is there an easy way of doing this? I mean is there a theme or some method?

Any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Buttons` and set `compoundDrawable` to it.
You can check out one of my sililar posts **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665385/android-how-to-display-4-text-views-with-icons/16665594#16665594)**. Just replace the `TextView` with `Button`.
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for reply, but do you think it is possible to use buttons instead of "items" in action bar? I mean, I have "onOptionsItemSelected" event in my activity, and buttons are not selected, they are pressed.